# How do I create a facet grid with scatterplots comparing numeric values corresponding to 5 different factors to each other in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I feel like I'm going to have difficulty explaining this but I'll do my best.

Let's say I have two types of data I want to plot: factor levels and "TWAS.P" values:

```
> final %>% select(BPcum, type, TWAS.P)
            BPcum type   TWAS.P
    1:     910406  aoi 0.447942
    2:     913192  aoi 0.343688
    3:     918941  aoi 0.507661
    4:     934255  aoi 0.602502
    5:     963152  aoi 0.821883
   ---                         
61176: 2871588859   si 0.049800
61177: 2871696719   si 0.434000
61178: 2871742389   si 0.480000
61179: 2871747173   si 0.989000
61180: 2871747464   si 0.442000
> table(final %>% select(type))

  aoi   cpd   dpw    sc    si 
12244 12244 12244 12244 12204
```

I want to create a matrix of plots that shows, for example, `aoi` `TWAS.P` values plotted against `TWAS.P` values of every other "type" of `TWAS.P` value. So a plot that shows `aoi TWAS.P` values plotted against, say, `cpd TWAS.P` values, another that shows `aoi TWAS.P` values plotted against `dpw TWAS.P` values, and so on. If necessary, I want them to be matched on `BPcum`.

I want to be able to discover if there is any correlation between the `TWAS.P` values of each `type`. I can intuit that I would need to use `dplyr`'s `pivot_longer` but I'm not sure how to get there.

The closest I could figure out is using `ggpairs`, though it doesn't exactly get where I wanted:

```
ggpairs(
    final %>% select(type, TWAS.Z),
    ggplot2::aes(colour = type),
    upper = list(continuous = "points", combo = "dot"),
    lower = list(continuous = "points", combo = "dot")
)
```

[image: ggpairs_plot]

If you look at the plot in the top right panel, it's close to what I'm looking for. However, I want a facet grid of each `type`'s `TWAS.Z` values being compared to each other for each row so that any correlation can be elucidated.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by "I want them to be matched on BPcum". Could you explain?

Comment: Is "BPcum" like an "ID" of each observation so we know how to match each value of "aoi" to the other types (cpd, dpw, sc, si). For example, in row 1 BPcum = 910406 for "aoi". So, there will be a row of "cpd" where BPcum = 910406 too? Is this what you meant by "matched on BPcum"?

Comment: @kikoralston yes

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another, better way to do this using old code that I had used before. It does not use `BPcum` but rather a combination of ENSEMBL gene ID and gene symbol. I used `dcast` from base R to accomplish this:

```
final_2 <-
    select(final, geneid, genesymbol, type, TWAS.Z, TWAS.P) %>%
    as.data.table()

final_2$type <- as.factor(final$type)

final_wide <-
        dcast(final_2,
              geneid + genesymbol ~ type,
              value.var = c("TWAS.P"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you need to use a combination of `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer` to separate in different columns the data that you want in the x-axis ("aoi") and the data you want in the y-axis (the rest). Your dataframe is already in long format, but all your data is in the same column.

Here is how I did it.

```
library(tidyverse)

# create dataset
set.seed(100)
types <- c("aoi", "cpd", "dpw", "sc", "si")
A <- matrix(runif(5^2)*2-1, ncol=5) 
Sigma <- t(A) %*% A
values <- as.vector(mvrnorm(n=2000, mu=rep(0,5), Sigma))

df.1 <- data.frame(BPcum=rep(1:2000, 5),
                   type=rep(types, rep(2000, 5)),
                   values=values)

# convert to "wide" format (each type in one column)
# note that it is important here that BPcum identifies each observation coherently (i.e., there are no duplicates)
df.wide <- df.1 %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from=values)

# now convert back to "long", but leave aoi in its own column 
df.long <- df.wide %>% dplyr::select(-BPcum) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols=-aoi)

# create plot  
ggplot(df.long) + geom_point(aes(x=aoi, y=value)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(name), nrow=1)
```

Another way to plot this would be to use base R `pairs` to create a scatterplot matrix. The difference is that you would have scatter plots for all combinations of the types. In this case you would only need to create the "wide" dataframe (and remove the `BPcum` column).

```
pairs(df.wide %>% select(-BPcum))
```